# Importing node and express with typings in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up a TypeScript express/node application in Visual Studio Code following the [Microsoft guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_typings) but changing it to use TypeScript however when it comes to installing the type definitions using `typings` I seem to have to install more packages than the guide.

I'm running the following pair of commands:

```
typings install node --ambient --save
typings install express --ambient --save
```

However attempting to build with just those packages gives the following type of error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serve-static'.
```

For the following typings:

- mime
- express-serve-static-core
- serve-static

I can resolve this by installing the required typings but it seems like something typings should do by itself.

I wanted to check if I was missing a fundamental step to automatically pull in dependencies or whether the guide was outdated?

In case it's relevant, my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "bin",
        "sourceRoot": "src"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser"
    ]
}
```

My tsc is version 1.8.7 and I have typescript installed globally.

Comment: While it would be great if it pulled the ambient declarations today, it currently doesn't and it likely won't change.  See [this issue](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/113) as well as [this comment](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/281#issuecomment-192551121)

Comment: Just a side note that "ambient" is deprecated now: `typings ERR! deprecated The "ambient" flag is deprecated. Please use "global" instead`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of the release of TypeScript 2.0 last month, the recommended tool for installing typings is our trusty old friend `npm` instead of `typings` or `tsd`.

```
npm install @types/node --save
```

With npm, there's no need to worry about "global" or "ambient" installations anymore.

You also don't need to worry about adding `<reference>` tags to the top of your source files anymore; just drop the following property into your `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`, and the TypeScript compiler will automatically find the npm typings you've installed:

```
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ]
```

Here's a blog post that explains the change in some more detail: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: `@types`modules are defined as the default for typedeclarations in typescript 2. For this reason `"typeroots" : [ "node_modules/@types` ]` is unnecessary as long as it is the only typing folder.

Comment: This is incredible! What a life-saver. Typings was become quite the pain in the arse

Comment: I haven't had any time to look at TypeScript for a long while but this seems to work for me now. I've changed this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

The tutorial I linked has now been updated to include the following commands:

```
typings install node --ambient
typings install express serve-static express-serve-static-core --ambient
```

See @cdbajorin 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013174/importing-node-and-express-with-typings-in-typescript#comment59687670_36013174) for information about why dependencies are not automatically downloaded.

Comment: _--ambient_ has been renamed to _--global_ in [typings-1.0.0](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

Comment: Also (as far as I can make out) the default repository for installation is now npm.  There's a new repository added called env which contains type declarations for environments (such as node).  I used:

`typings install env~node@4.0.0 --save --global`

Not sure if the situation with the global dependencies of your dependencies has changed with this.

Answer (score 2):

to save everyone a headache, the magic command to get the typings for node is now:

`typings install node --source env --global --save`