# How to install express in typings?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

I am trying to use expressjs in my app.

After installing it using `typings install express --ambient --save`, I run `tsc`, but I get two errors:

> typings/main/ambient/express/index.d.ts(17,34): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'serve-static'.
>   typings/main/ambient/express/index.d.ts(18,27): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'express-serve-static-core'.

So, I tried to install both:

```
typings install serve-static --ambient --save
typings install express-serve-static --ambient --save
```

and then I run tsc again, but get one more error:

> typings/main/ambient/serve-static/index.d.ts(79,24): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'mime'.

How can I solve these problems? How can I install all dependencies of express automatically?

Answer (score 17):

With Typescript 2.0(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/), now it is different:

If you install typescript with the following command:

```
npm install -g typescript@2.0
```

You will have to install express typings with command

```
npm install --save @types/express
```

Instead of typings getting installed with ambient/global like in earlier releases. The typings get installed in `node_modules/@types/express` directory

Your package.json will have the following fragment after doing `npm install` of `types` :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.33"
  }
```

Comment: must the version of `@types/express` be the very same as the one for `express`?

Answer (score 10):

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160715232503",
    "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160606155157"
  }
}
```

This is my working Typings.json

Comment: This whole time.... in my typings.json for my error: -> "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160715232503"     somehow I got version 0.0.0 and had to manually change it to 4.0.0 then run
     typings install dt~express-serve-static-core --global --save

Comment: Why aren't these installed along with express? Are these peer dependencies?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this myself and I believe is a duplicate from :

[Importing node and express with typings in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013174/importing-node-and-express-with-typings-in-typescript)

I installed both serve-static and express-serve-static then got errors stating that I was missing 'mime' and 'http'.

I had to install node typings to resolve the missing http reference and mime typings to resolve mime missing reference.

```
typings install mime --ambient --save
typings install node --ambient --save
```

Comment: With typings 1.0, I believe this is now: `typings install dt~mime --global --save`

Comment: And now (Oct 2016) the correct command is `typings install mime --global --save --source dt`

Answer (score 5):

The command that worked for me (the day I posted) was :
`typings install dt~express --global --save`
(ambient was replaced by global)

To find other related module you can use the command `typings search express` (it also give you the source info)

Answer (score 0):

I'v run into this issue myself and found out you also have to have **the actual nodeJS module installed as well as its typing**.

So when you have correclty configured typescript and your project, you need ot install both the nodeJS dependency as well as the @types dependecy.

`npm install express --save`

`npm install --save @types/express`