# Declaration types in typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I have been making a webpage for the past two days and I have chosen to use TypeScript.

I have chosen Express.js as the web server, and I have used Express in the past so I know about Express.

I saw that TypeScript looks highly at each property and what properties have, and I have a problem with this because the property "user" is not set by default and I want to use it to save the decoded user session.

After searching online, I found this:

```typescript
declare module "express" { // declare module "express-serve-static-core"
  export interface Request {
    user: any
  }
}
```

from this post: [Typescript Error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383387/typescript-error-property-user-does-not-exist-on-type-request)

I pasted that into a file and it works well but I have two problems:

1. I don't know why it works. I don't require the file but however this works, the unique that I made is to require it this in typeroots inside tsconfig.json but executing with ts-node. I don't know if it has any effect (in fact, Visual Studio Code does not throw an error but ts-node does).
2. I want to give user the type Session, so I imported Session into the file, but now Visual Studio Code tells me that is not in the User property.

Comment: To answer question #2, I'll need to see the corresponding version of the code you tried and the exact text of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`module` - is a global namespace for types. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) .

> A namespace is a way to logically group related code. This is inbuilt
>   into TypeScript unlike in JavaScript where variables declarations go
>   into a global scope and if multiple JavaScript files are used within
>   same project there will be possibility of overwriting or misconstruing
>   the same variables, which will lead to the “global namespace pollution
>   problem” in JavaScript.

[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_namespaces.htm)

It's better to `npm install --save @types/express` as it has better types coverage.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** In standard TypeScript-based tools such as `tsc` and Visual Studio Code that process an entire project, a module augmentation like yours in any file of your project (based on the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` settings in `tsconfig.json`) is automatically in effect for all files in your project that use the original module; there is no need to explicitly reference the file containing the augmentation.  However, `ts-node` defaults to only passing files to TypeScript as they are loaded at runtime ([documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing)).  You can use the `--files` option to get `ts-node` to pass the entire project to TypeScript.  (This will be enough for your module augmentation to work, though note that this still does not eagerly *load* all files at runtime.  To do that, you would have to use `import` or `require`, and then you'd no longer need `--files`.)