# Express use custom typed middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to write authentication logic for my app. I wrote a middleware that verifies a token, and therefore I need `req.id`. I had to write an interface that extends from `express.Request` to be able to access `id` ([similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383387/typescript-error-property-user-does-not-exist-on-type-request)).

```
import { Request } from "express";

export interface IGetUserAuthInfoRequest extends Request {
    id: number;
}
```

This is how I implement the interface in my middleware to be able to use the `req.id` property.

```
export const verifyToken = (req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    req.id = 1; // do something with req.id
    /**
     * some more logic
     **/ 
    next(); 
}
```

When I try calling the middleware, TypeScript complains, I think this is because of the custom type.

```
app.get("/api/try/admin", verifyToken, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json({message: "try admin"})
});
```

The error looks something like this.

```
Type '(req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) 
=> Response | void' is not assignable to type 
'ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | 
RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<...>>'.
```

How could I type this correctly (preferably without using `any`)?

Comment: Make id as a optional  prop. `id?: number;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom middleware is not compatible with (not a subtype of) the base Express middleware type.

Your custom middleware's `req` *parameter* is more specialized than the base middleware's `Request` parameter. In [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) language, your custom middleware is NOT contravariant with the base Express middleware in their argument types. Function argument contravariance is a requirement for substitution/subtyping.

One solution to this is to turn off `strictFunctionChecks` in `tsconfig.json` to allow [function parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance). Another way is to change your custom request parameter's type to make it compatible with the base type:

```
interface IGetUserAuthInfoRequest extends Request {
  id?: number // making this optional will make your custom middleware type-compatible
}
```

With these workarounds, your custom middleware will be accepted by `app.get`, BUT its customized `req` parameter will NOT be propagated to succeeding middlewares and request/error handlers. That is, `req.id` will still be type `undefined` instead of `number | undefined` in other places (it will only be typed inside your custom middleware).

I think the proper solution to this is to use declaration-merging and merge your custom `Request` interface to the `Express` namespace. Express [exposes this feature for custom middlewares to use](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/ts4.0/index.d.ts#L4-L12):

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // These open interfaces may be extended in an application-specific manner via declaration merging.
        // See for example method-override.d.ts (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/method-override/index.d.ts)
        interface Request {}
        interface Response {}
        interface Application {}
    }
}
```

To merge your custom middleware's `Request` interface:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      id?: number
    }
  }
}
```